# Erro ao remover acentos de uma string para criação de URL's amigáveis

Tags: php, string, url-amigável

Ola gostaria de saber como posso contornar o erro que esta sendo ocasionado no código abaixo.Quando coloco acentuações caracteres especiais eles estão sendo retirados ao invés de convertido.

Eu peguei este código com um amigo já faz um tempo e do nada começou a apresentar esse erro em vários hosts de hospedagem não sei se foi por causa da atualização do PHP mais em todo caso gostaria de saber por que esta apresentando este erro.

O erro literalmente e que esta sendo tirando os caracteres especiais e acentuações e colocando no lugar deles o valor da variável `$slug` ou seja se o valor da `$slug` for um traço tira a acentuações e caracteres especiais e poem traço no lugar ao invés de converter.

**Exemplo funcionando antes:**

Testando conversão de texto para URL amigável 1 = testando-conversao-de-texto-para-url-amigavel-1

Ação, Comédia = acao-comedia

**Exemplo do erro atual:**

Testando conversão de texto para URL amigável 1 = testando-convers-o-de-texto-para-url-amig-vel-1

Ação, Comédia = a-o-comdia

Literalmente os caracteres que estavam sendo convertidos estão sendo deletados como posso concertar isso ?

```
   function removeAcentos($string, $slug = false) {
      $string = strtolower($string);

      // Código ASCII das vogais
      $ascii['a'] = range(224, 230);
      $ascii['e'] = range(232, 235);
      $ascii['i'] = range(236, 239);
      $ascii['o'] = array_merge(range(242, 246), array(240, 248));
      $ascii['u'] = range(249, 252);

      // Código ASCII dos outros caracteres
      $ascii['b'] = array(223);
      $ascii['c'] = array(231);
      $ascii['d'] = array(208);
      $ascii['n'] = array(241);
      $ascii['y'] = array(253, 255);

      foreach ($ascii as $key=>$item) {
        $acentos = '';
        foreach ($item AS $codigo) $acentos .= chr($codigo);
        $troca[$key] = '/['.$acentos.']/i';
      }

      $string = preg_replace(array_values($troca), array_keys($troca), $string);

      // Slug?
      if ($slug) {
        // Troca tudo que não for letra ou número por um caractere ($slug)
        $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', $slug, $string);
        // Tira os caracteres ($slug) repetidos
        $string = preg_replace('/' . $slug . '{2,}/i', $slug, $string);
        $string = trim($string, $slug);
      }

      return $string;
    }
echo removeAcentos(Ação, Comédia, Ficção Cientifica, '-');
```

Exemplo do Código funcionando para mostrar o erro [clique aqui](https://ideone.com/65AnAJ)

Comment: Corrigi minha resposta. Agora creio que isso resolva seu problema.;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você quer apenas converter os acentos para letras comuns?

Utilize a função `iconv`.

Então faça assim:

```
echo iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', 'Pêra maçã côco');
```

Saída:

> Pera maca coco

Veja funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/aXNjJw)

Comment: Funciona legal mais tipo só converte textos necessito que no caso faça conversão de qualquer tipo de caractere ou simbolo colocando também - entre os espaços. Mais em todo caso grato pela ajuda.